# Query with Rolling Sub Totals and Percentages

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select
    DrugName,
    DrugCategoryName,
    count(*) as Count,,
    'Percentage of Total' as Percentage
from
    Visit V
Inner Join Drug D on
    V.DrugID = D.DrugID
Inner Join DrugCategory DC on
    D.DrugCategoryID = DC.DrugCategoryID
where
    V.StartDate >='01 Feb 2017' and V.EndDate < '01 Mar 2017'
group by
    DrugName, DrugCategoryName
```

which gives the following results:

[image]

What I need to be able to get is a get a result like the below:

[image: 0]

Which Sub Totals by the Category, and shows a Percentage of the Total.

How could I go about getting this done without keeping a Cursor or another type of Loop?

Comment: Can you do something with Images instead of tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the ratio using window functions (and multiply by 100 if you really want a "percentage").

You can calculate the subtotals using `GROUPING SETS`.  Read more about them [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select DrugName, DrugCategoryName,
       count(*) as Count,
       count(*) / sum(1.0 * count(*)) over () as Percentage
from Visit V Inner Join
     Drug D on
     V.DrugID = D.DrugID Inner Join
     DrugCategory DC
     on D.DrugCategoryID = DC.DrugCategoryID
where V.StartDate >= '2017-02-01' and V.EndDate < '2017-03-01'
group by grouping sets ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName), (DrugCategoryName))
```

EDIT:

I suspect that `grouping sets` and windows functions don't work so well together.  So, how about this:

```
select DrugName, DrugCategoryName, sum(Count)
from (select DrugName, DrugCategoryName,
             count(*) as Count,
             count(*) / sum(1.0 * count(*)) over () as Percentage
      from Visit V Inner Join
           Drug D on
           V.DrugID = D.DrugID Inner Join
           DrugCategory DC
           on D.DrugCategoryID = DC.DrugCategoryID
      where V.StartDate >= '2017-02-01' and V.EndDate < '2017-03-01'
      group by grouping DrugName, DrugCategoryName
     ) vdc
group by grouping sets ( (DrugName, DrugCategoryName, Percentage), (DrugCategoryName));
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon. Works perfectly except for one issue where its calculating the percentage based off the sub totals also when it shouldn't. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @James . . . That is really curious.  Is it doing that for all rows?

Comment: If percentage is to be NULL for subtotals, change the third line to `case when DrugName is not null then count(*) / sum(1.0 * count(*)) over () end as Percentage`

Comment: Thanks dean, that did the trick. @Gordon Linoff - I've tried adding the multiply by 100 but I keep getting syntax errors. Where do I need to add this? This is what I'm trying currently. case when DrugName is not null then (count(*) / sum(1.0 * count(*)) * 100) over () end as Percentage

Comment: The strange thing as well is that the Percentage calculation doesn't seem to be working correctly, because it only totals up to 50%. What's missing there? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff - for some reason it didn't notify me of your edited post.  It fails on this line though - group by grouping DrugName, DrugCategoryName . I changed it to  group by grouping sets ((DrugName, DrugCategoryName)) but the percentages are all wrong. Any idea what you may have missed here?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I changed your original query to include this for Percentage and it is nicely formatted - case when DrugName is not null then  CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()) end as Percentage so ideally something similar in the finalised one would be ideal.

Comment: Siorry Gordon, on second look its working perfectly. Thanks very much for your help.